# Align Cursor/Origins to a smooth corner

Tags: origin

So anyone know how I can align the origin/Curso so that it hist the point this two vert meet?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you set Header > Options to 'Origins' in Object mode, all the usual snapping and transform constraints are available, as if the origin was any other object.

[image]

Here, Snap set to 'Vertex' and 'Active' , <kbd>G</kbd> snapping to a vertex on one edge, and then <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> snapping to the X of the other edge.

If the edges are not conveniently aligned to World or Local X,Y or Z, you might have to create a Custom Transform Orientation from the first edge, and then <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> in that orientation to snap in line, to the second edge.

Answer (score 1):

A quick method which will only work if your edges are along the axis as they are in your image and the object is not rotated.

On the <kbd>N</kbd> panel, click the <kbd>View</kbd> tab then <kbd>Shift-click</kbd> on the <kbd>3D Cursor</kbd> header to pin it to the panel:

[image]

Now select one of the edges and use <kbd>Shift-S</kbd> > <kbd>Cursor to Selected</kbd> to move the cursor to that edge:
[image]

Select the other edge and open the <kbd>Item</kbd> tab on the <kbd>N</kbd> panel. <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> copy the X position from the <kbd>Transform Median</kbd> entry and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> paste it into the <kbd>3D Cursor</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> position location.

[image]

Job done!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Mode, select and duplicate the edges that are not bevelled. Press  <kbd>P</kbd>  to separate them from the original object if necessary.

[image]

Then go up to auto merge vertices and click that on.

[image]

Also check "split edges" from the options menu.

[image]

In edit mode, drag the end points to their intersection point.  Press <kbd>G</kbd> then  <kbd>X</kbd>  (or Y) to snap the move along an axis.

[image]

[image]

Select the new vertex. Press  <kbd>shift+s</kbd> and choose `cursor to selected` to move the cursor to the point.

**Approach 2**
You can make corners using the  "Tiny CAD" add-on.  It comes with Blender.  In Edit Mode, select two edges and  <kbd>right click</kbd> and  choose `Tiny CAD> X-auto`.  It will create corners.  You can select the vert and move the 3d cursor/origin to that point.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do i do the 4th step? Dragging them together? is there a way to make them move to different directions? Since anything i do try i can seem to make them to move an the same time. unless you mean to move them separately

Comment: I did it separately, but locked them along an axis.  I have edited my answer.